# where is dockerfile and how to add lines in it?

Tags: docker

I'm having an error `ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`, which I found that I have to add some lines in dockerfile.

I'm not familiar with docker, barely installed it, and using it with limited knowledge on know how to install/download images I need/create containers, and I need help with docker.

So, (1) where can I find a dockerfile, and (2) how can I edit it?
(I'm using **Ubuntu 18.08**)

ref. to fixing the above error is [here](https://exerror.com/importerror-libgl-so-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory/), just in case anyone is having the same issue!

Thank you so much for the help in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a textfile called `Dockerfile` in your project directory and put all your code in there.

Example:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y <your-dependencys>

COPY . .
```

2nd line installs packages on the image.

3rd line copys every file in your current directory to the image.

Comment: so is it mean dockerfile is similar to an image file? If it is, is it possible to edit the downloaded image file in Linux before creating a container? I normally find an image file online that would fit my project, and create a container right away.

Comment: yes you can download a dockerfile and build a container from that.